# Execute/Run a single line in IPython rather entire Cell

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have often this problem, when I'm slicing or subsetting data that I want to view/print `[df.head()]` the data and look into into it before writing next line of my code. 
For this case, every time, I have to run the whole block(cell) in ipython, even if I have some logic written I had to comment that block and execute my print line alone.

Is there a feature where you can select a single line and execute it.

Comment: I usually make a new cell to do this. We have an idea for a web console that would sit in the corner of your notebook for quick commands.

Comment: ah! I sometimes do that! Having a separate console would be a great idea. Looking forward :)

Comment: The suggestion from David Smith is great! Please consider accepting it as the correct answer by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 33):

I often start a qtconsole attached to the kernel.  You can do that as follows:

1. Create a new cell.
2. In the new cell, type `%qtconsole` and execute that cell.
3. Delete the new cell.

Once you have a qtconsole that is attached to the notebook kernel.  You can print 
the value of variables there.

Comment: I know the general rule is against "thanks!" comments, but this is an extraordinarily useful trick I don't recall seeing elsewhere.  Multiple upvotes would be given if possible.

Comment: I did the above. How do I proceed with executing a single line? How do I access the console?

Comment: @sand - the `qtconsole` that appears in a separate window is linked to the notebook it was created from, meaning you can just type your one-liners in there, it will have access to the kernel's variables and functions. Then once you get the useful one-liner, for example, you can paste that into the actual workbook as required. This prevents making little "test cells" all over the place in the workbook.

Comment: "the qtconsole that appears in a separate window". Where is the separate window? I followed the %qtconsole instruction, but I don't see any window opening up.